# How to set the no cursor on a mouse move for a buttons?

Tags: vb.net

How to set the no cursor on a mouse move for a buttons in `vb.net`?
I have try to google it but, I did not find any example. Well what I try to do is wen the mouse is over a button change the mouse cursor to cursor.no or other like cursor.default
Well after try multiple different ways i have try like the example you show bellow but my buttons are disable by default wen the application load 
So the example bellow its not work with the disable buttons

```
Private Sub Button21_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button21.MouseEnter
    If TextBox6.Text = Nothing Then
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.No
    End If
    If TextBox6.Text <> "1a3390pohv-1974-pod-2017" Then
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.No
    End If
    If TextBox6.Text = "1a3390pohv-1974-pod-2017" Then
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Hand
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, or at least I don't understand what to want. Please [edit] your question and add more information about what you want to achieve

Comment: @Pikoh i have edit the question

Comment: See my edited answer, using a panel may solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a handler to the Form's MouseMove event. Since it's not in the Button's handler, instead of letting the Button handler figure out the in / out logic automatically (MouseEnter event), you need to check this logic yourself.

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
    Dim buttons = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
    Dim insideButton = True
    If sender Is Me AndAlso buttons.Count > 0 Then
        insideButton = False
        For Each button In buttons
            If e.X > button.Left _
                AndAlso e.X < button.Left + button.Width _
                AndAlso e.Y > button.Top _
                AndAlso e.Y < button.Top + button.Height Then
                insideButton = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    If insideButton Then
        Me.Cursor = getCursorState()
    Else
        ' not sure what the cursor should be when not on a button. set it here
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default 
    End If
End Sub

' the logic has been simplified
Private Function getCursorState() As Cursor
    If TextBox6.Text = "1a3390pohv-1974-pod-2017" Then
        Return Cursors.Hand
    Else
        Return Cursors.No
    End If
End Function
```

And we're going to use the same handler for mouse movement as well, to reuse code. There is some additional logic in the handler to accommodate the Form and Buttons. Add the handler to each Button at startup.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
        AddHandler button.MouseMove, AddressOf Form1_MouseMove
    Next
End Sub
```

Now, when a Button is disabled, the Form's mouse move handler is used. When a Button is enabled, its own mouse move handler is used.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to hide the mouse cursor when it's inside a `Button`, you can use the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events of the button, and use the [`Cursor.Show`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.show(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Cursor.Hide`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.hide(v=vs.110).aspx) methods:

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseEnter
    Cursor.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseLeave
    Cursor.Show()
End Sub
```

---

After your last edit, your problem seem to be that the button is disabled, and a disabled control does not throw events. An easy solution to that could be the following:

1. Add a `Panel` to your form, and put your button inside it (with `Dock.Fill`)
2. Instead of using the button `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave`, use the same events but of the container panel:

   ```
   Private Sub Panel1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseEnter
       If TextBox6.Text = Nothing Then
           Me.Cursor = Cursors.No
       End If
       If TextBox6.Text <> "1a3390pohv-1974-pod-2017" Then
           Me.Cursor = Cursors.No
       End If
       If TextBox6.Text = "1a3390pohv-1974-pod-2017" Then
           Me.Cursor = Cursors.Hand
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

And the same in the Panel1.MouseLeave

Comment: Answering a question that clearly does not have code does not help the OP in the long run. How do you know this is what the OP is doing?

Comment: `probably OP doesn't know about the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events so he/she does not know where to start` I understand, but we help fix problems that **do** exists, not throw code around guessing... Also the OP clearly lacked research... This is a low quality question, how come you didn't leave a comment suggesting to the OP where to look? On the right side, "Related" area, there are more than a few answers on SO that address this as well...

Comment: @Pikoh tanks for the help well this its solve part of the problem but my button will be disable on application load i have try but because the button is disable its not work at all

Answer (score -2):

If all you need is the cursor to change when your mouse is over that button, you can simply use
 `myBtn.Cursor = Cursor.No` when loading the form or in the designer.